# Let A, B, and C be sets. Which propositions are true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm practicing exam question for the exam in january.

I have chosen to highlight the true proposition in bold. Are there any other true propositions? Will you explain how I go about solving these exercises?

Let A, B, and C be sets. Which propositions are true?

- Answer 4.a: $$(A ∪ B)^C = A ∩ B  $$
- **Answer  4.b: $$A − B = A ∩ B^C$$** This is the set complement law. True.
- Answer 4.c: (A ∩ B) − C = (A − C) ∩ B
- Answer 4.d: (A ∪ B) ∩ C = (A ∩ C) ∪ (B ∩ C)
- Answer 4.e: (A ∪ B) − A = B

Comment: What is the meaning of $BC$?

Comment: Do you mean $A\cap B^c$? For $4a$ have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Have you searched on this site already? There are many helpful posts here.  What did you try with $4.e$?

Comment: Hi manooooh. I meant B raised to the exponent C. $$B^C$$

Hi mfl. Yes I had already written double $ prior to posting it, but somehow I managed to omit the ^. I have fixed it. Thank you for the link to De Morgan's laws, but I've already tried those and I fail at utilizing them properly. Maybe you could give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Cornman's answer - 4.c) is in fact **true**.

From 4.b) we know that $ A - B = A \cap B^c $. So in 4.c) we have:

$ (A \cap B) − C = (A \cap B) \cap C^c = $ {intersection is associative and commutative} $ = (A \cap C^c) \cap B = (A − C) ∩ B $